# Bootstrap table with multiple row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a "large" table to be beautiful in both mobile devices and desktop. Without x-scrolling.

One way, I think, is to create a table row which is high (two rows, with rowspan=2).

But is there a smoother and more good-looking way to make this? This example below is okay, but I still think it's possible to make the result more clean and nicer.

One problem is also that I can't use ant filter plugins and pagination, as the scripts think that one row is two rows.

Any ideas?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="bg-danger">
          <td rowspan=2>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle btn-md" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="">+
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                <li class="bg-danger"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <h4>Christian A</h4></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h4 class="pull-right">133 €</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-danger">
          <td colspan=2>
            2014-05-05 - Not paid
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-success">
          <td rowspan=2>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle btn-md" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="">+
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                <li class="bg-danger"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <h4>Nicolaus S</h4></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h4 class="pull-right">122 €</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-success">
          <td colspan=2>
            2014-05-05 - Payed
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/weuf6vb3/

Comment: If not all columns need to be seen in mobile, you can set up media queries to hide some columns to prevent any x-axis scrolling.

Comment: Hi @DrewKennedy ! That's a good way of doing it, but I really want all columns to be seen in both mobile and desktop!